# encrypt string through url and retrieve on next page?

Tags: php, encryption

I am using the following php script to encrypt a string when i pass it through a url.

The majority of my code is stored in my encryption.php file.

encryption.php:

```
<?php class encryption{
    private $config;

    public function __construct( $options=array() ){
        $this->config=array_merge(
            array(
                'cipher'    =>  MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                'mode'      =>  MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
                'key'       =>  FALSE,
                'iv'        =>  FALSE,
                'size'      =>  FALSE,
                'base64'    =>  TRUE,
                'salt'      =>  FALSE
            ),
            $options
        );
    }
    private function getivs( $config=object ){
        $config->size=mcrypt_get_iv_size( $config->cipher, $config->mode );
        $config->iv=mcrypt_create_iv( $config->size, MCRYPT_RAND );
    }
    public function encrypt( $data=NULL ){
        $config=(object)$this->config;
        $this->getivs( $config );
        $data=trim( $data );
        $module = mcrypt_module_open( $config->cipher, '', $config->mode, '' );
        mcrypt_generic_init( $module, $config->key, $config->iv );

        $output = $config->base64 ? base64_encode( mcrypt_generic( $module, $data ) ) : mcrypt_generic( $module, $data );

        mcrypt_generic_deinit( $module );
        mcrypt_module_close( $module );
        return $output;
    }
    public function decrypt( $data=NULL ){
        $config=(object)$this->config;
        $this->getivs( $config );
        mb_detect_order( 'auto' );
        $encoding=mb_detect_encoding( $data );
        if( !$data or is_null( $data ) or empty( $data ) or !$encoding or $data=='' or base64_decode( $data )=='' ) return FALSE;

        $module = mcrypt_module_open( $config->cipher, '', $config->mode, '' );
        mcrypt_generic_init( $module, $config->key, $config->iv );

        $output = $config->base64 ? rtrim( mdecrypt_generic( $module, base64_decode( $data ) ),"\0" ) : rtrim( mdecrypt_generic( $module, $data ),"\0" );

        mcrypt_generic_deinit( $module );
        mcrypt_module_close( $module );
        return urldecode( $output );
    }
}//end class

?>
```

I then call my function and pass my string as an encrypted string through the url in my track_request.php file:

```
require_once 'dependables/encryption.php';
        $string = 'NS' . substr( md5(rand()), 0, 7);
        $enc=new encryption( array( 'key'=>'PlowFish' ) );
        $encrypted_string = $enc->encrypt( $string );


        echo '<a href="ns_application.php?ns_request='.$encrypted_string.'">Click</a>
```

Lastly i then retrieve the encrypted string and decrypt it again on my ns_application.php page:

```
require_once 'dependables/encryption.php';
$reference = isset($_GET['ns_request']) ? $_GET['ns_request'] : null;
$enc=new encryption( array( 'key'=>'PlowFish' ) );

$decrypted_string=$enc->decrypt( $reference ); ?>


<?php echo $decrypted_string; ?>
```

The problem is this script works 5 times out of 10, and i will end up with a decrypted string with something that looks like 'NS1H57347' or 'NS197G347' and on and on etc.

However the other 5 times it will fail and it won't decrypt at all so i end up with a really long encrypted string like: 'FJQRU248T\£$90=}\31232HGfd*,^='

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong? thanks

Comment: you're not urlencoding your string, so whatever url metacharacters exist in that binary "garbage" of the encrypted string are going to be DECODED on the receiving end.

Comment: why not put it in a session, then no enctyption needed

Comment: @Dagon thanks for the suggestion but i would prefer not to use a session if i can get this to work

Comment: @Marc B has the correct ansewer, however using encryption this way seems very over engineered. If you end up with > 2K data after encryption + encoding this will start to break down. If you need close to that, even if you use cookies instead of _SESSION or another type of cache you'r going to increase the load time of pages (again, depending on data size). Finally, does it need to be encrypted at all? If you use HTTPS only, you and the end user are the only people who will know what is in the url.

Comment: "i would prefer not to use a session if i can get this to work" ... WHY?